# Are nose wheel tyres designed differently from the main wheel tyres?

Tags: landing-gear, airbus-a380, boeing-747, tire

For the heavy large Jumbos like the Airbus A380 and the Boeing 747-800, considering nosewheel tyres are not subjected to the excessive heating caused by braking from the disks and brake pads, and frictional heat on the outer surfaces caused by contact with the tarmark surfaces and braking, are nose wheel tyres designed and manufactured differently from those of the main gear and do they cost more or less.  Considering they are not fitted with brakes, What is their temperature at landing after and are there instruments to measure this? If not why not?

Comment: The last bit is duplicated from [your question specifically on tire temperature](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48199/1696).

Comment: FWIW, for the 747-100/200 aircraft, in general the nose wheel tires are the same as the main gear tires. I say in general because not all 747 models necessarily use the same main gear tires depending on some of the weight upgrades, and also, JALs short-range, high density models had heavier gear as I remember. The main gear wheels had temperature monitoring, but never the nose gear. Don't forget, though, that taxiing exerts considerable side loads on the hose tires when turning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wheels on the 747-400 are the same all round.

One operator I worked with had a mixed fleet of -400 and -200s. They used the -200 wheels on the -400 nosewheel (mainwheels had to be -400).